# assembly mips and carriage return

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this issue using assembly MIPS. 
From the keyboard I read an integer and the range must be 1..20

```
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t2,$v0        # value read

blez $t2,err1       # if $t2 <0 go to error1 function
bgt $t2,20,err1     # if $t2 >20 go to error1 function
```

I want to add a default integer value and if the user clicks the Enter key (.byte 0x0d 0x0a ) the program should continue. How can I do this?

E.g.

```
Insert in position 6 [return confirm/overwrite old]: <1,2,3..20>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a dummy program which reads a number just like you did then it prints out what it has just read. Run it, press enter and you know what to look for. :)